# C# use LINQ to query custom list and return new subset list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a custom type called Holdings. I am trying to query the list based on one property of the Holdings object to return a new list of Holdings. The LINQ query below does work correctly but I would like to replace var unitHld with List unitHld but can't get the code to work.

```
var unitHld = from hld in _holdingList
              where hld.FundCode == lookThroList[i].FundCode
              select new Holding() { Currency = hld.Currency, 
                                     FundCode = lookThroList[i].FundCode, 
                                     IdSedol = hld.IdSedol, 
                                     Nominal = hld.Nominal * unitWgt, 
                                     Price = hld.Price };
```

This new list is then slightly altered before being added back to the original list (I know the logic sounds strange but please accept this is how it has to be done). However because unitHld is var the line below does not work.

```
_holdingList.Add(unitHld);
```

Comment: Try `_holdingList.AddRange(unitHld);`

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You getting an error..?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, that is more like an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following call only adds a single item (where the item must be the same type as the list's elements):

```
_holdingList.Add(unitHld);
```

But you want to add a range of items, so do it like this:

```
_holdingList.AddRange(unitHld);
```

where `unitHld` is `IEnumerable<T>` and T is the type of the list's elements.

(This answer assumes that `holdingList` is of type `List<T>`, and that T is in fact `Holding` for your example.)

See [`List.AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

C# is statically typed.

`var` is not a type, all it does is a shortcut for in your case typing `IEnumerable<Holding>`.

If you want the result to be `List<Holding>` then all you need to do is wrap your query in brackets and put `.ToList()` at the end.

However, to append this to another list, you don't need to do that. Simply call `.AddRange` on the other list.

Alternatively, you can use `Concat`

```
var bothLists = aList.Concat(anotherList);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to replace `var unitHld` with `List unitHld` but can't get the code to work.

You need to call `ToList()` on the result of the query:

```
var unitHld = from hld in _holdingList
              where hld.FundCode == lookThroList[i].FundCode
              select new Holding() { Currency = hld.Currency, 
                                     FundCode = lookThroList[i].FundCode, 
                                     IdSedol = hld.IdSedol, 
                                     Nominal = hld.Nominal * unitWgt, 
                                     Price = hld.Price };
List<Holding> unitHldList = unitHld.ToList();
```

> This new list is then slightly altered before being added back to the original list

Once the data is in `unitHldList`, you can alter it as needed.

> the line below does not work. `_holdingList.Add(unitHld);`

When you add the content of a collection to a `List<T>`, use `AddRange` method instead of `Add`:

```
_holdingList.AddRange(unitHldList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_holdingList.AddRange(unitHld);
```